# Collectors.toMap of Map<String, List<Object>> are not able to resolve

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have this peace of code working fine, that takes a `Map<String, List<Device>>` and sort time and return the same datastructure:

```
Stream<Map.Entry<String, List<Device>>> results = device.getDeviceMapList().entrySet().stream();

Map<String, List<Device>> sortedMap = new HashMap<String, List<Device>>();

results.forEach(e -> {
    e.getValue().sort(Comparator.comparing(Device::getStationTimeStamp));
    sortedMap.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
});
```

Now I tried to use `Collectors.toMap` and did not successes:

```
Map<String, List<Device>> sortedMap = results.forEach(e -> {
    e.getValue().stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Device::getStationTimeStamp))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(e.getKey(), ArrayList<Device>::new));

});
```

The part `.collect(Collectors.toMap(e.getKey(), ArrayList<Device>::new));` is what I tried and it is not fully correct, what I have done wrong?

Comment: Why do you wrap the `.sorted(...).collect(...)` in a `forEach()` ?

Comment: More specifically, what isn't working? Is there an exception? Is the result not sorted the way you expect? What is the desired result? Examples of desired output and actual output help a lot.

Comment: in the first on it sorts but the one with collect does not compile, the input and output should be the same, the only diffenece the list of device should be sorted after timestamp

Comment: @RobinTopper I just copied the first code that is working and tried to use collect on it, I might have done it wrong,

Comment: Try to produce a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and give us an example of the output you would like to see. At the moment your problem is hard to reproduce.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To reproduce your problem I have created an example Map

```
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> mapA = new HashMap<>();
mapA.put(1, Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,8,7,6,9));
mapA.put(2, Arrays.asList(1,2,3,5,4,6,7,8,9));
mapA.put(3, Arrays.asList(2,3,1,4,5,6,7,8,9));
mapA.put(4, Arrays.asList(1,2,8,4,6,5,7,3,9));
mapA.put(5, Arrays.asList(9,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1));
```

and turned this into a Stream similar to yours

```
Stream<Map.Entry<Integer, List<Integer>>> results = mapA.entrySet().stream();
```

As you may have noticed, the Lists in mapA are not sorted.

To get a `Map<Integer,List<Integer>>` with the `List` sorted, you can do the following

```
Map<Integer,List<Integer>> sortedMap =          
        results.collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s.getKey(), 
                                         s -> s.getValue().stream()
          .sorted(Comparator.naturalOrder()).collect(Collectors.toList())));
```

You will have to replace the `Comparator.naturalOrder()` with `Comparator.comparing(Device::getStationTimeStamp)`.

Comment: first of all I was going to post a minimal code, but second of all it is not necessary because your solution did solve my question, thx dude since my list is device object so I did change it to .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Device::getStationTimeStamp))